# « Mener à » ou « amener à » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, préfixes

Lorsque ces verbes ne prennent pas le sens propre, je n'arrive pas à comprendre quelles sont les différences entre ces deux. Par exemple:

> Ce chemin (a)mène à la maison.
>   Où (a)mène cette route?
>   Ton diplôme (a)mène à tout.
>   Tous les chemins (a)mènent à Rome.
>   La débauche (a)mène à la ruine.
>   Ce chemin vous (a)mènera au lac.
>   Cela nous (a)mène à croire que...
>   Tu nous (a)mènes le soleil.
>   Les rats ont (a)mené cette maladie.
>   Il me fut impossible de les (a)mener à accepter le compromis.

Y a-t-il des différences entre les deux?
Peut-on les utiliser indifféremment?

Comment: Petite astuce utile, **remplace le verbe par ""conduire""**. Si ""conduire"" convient, utilise ""mener"" (car les deux sont **synonymes**), sinon utilise amener. C'est une **technique de substitution**, et ca marche pour beaucoup d'autres mots. Et donc non, tu vois bien avec ça que amener et mener ne s'utilisent pas indifféremment car ils n'ont pas le même sens.

Answer (score 6):

« Amener » est un verbe d’action, l’action de mener un sujet à un endroit.
« Mener » indique juste que le sujet permet d’amener à un endroit.

Dans votre première phrase

> Ce chemin (a)mène à la maison.

le bon verbe à utiliser est **mener**, car quoi qu’il arrive ce chemin permettra toujours de mener à la maison.
En revanche, dans

> Tu nous (a)mènes le soleil.

le verbe à utiliser est **amener** car *Tu* nous amènes le soleil à l’instant, mais peut-être que demain ce ne sera plus le cas.

Il est à noter que *mener* est de plus en plus utilisé en remplacement de *diriger*, et que *amener* tend à être de plus en plus utilisé là où *mener* serait plus logique.